# About The Order Of An Element In A Group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> The order, sometimes period, of an element a of a group is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m = e$ (where e denotes the identity element of the group, and am denotes the product of m copies of a). If no such m exists, a is said to have infinite order. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)#Counting_by_order_of_elements)

So we actually count the smallest number of operations needed to get the the identity element.

Just to make sure I am 100% on in

If we take $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and addition (Modulo 6) $o(3)=2$ as 3+3=0  (Modulo 6)?

And the order of the identity element will always be $1$

Comment: yes this is correct

Comment: It ıs correct. As you know smallest positive integer m such that $0m=0$ is just $1$.

Comment: Actually, I wonder that is there any purpose of this definition or this definition is natural.

Comment: Sec, If we go by the definition of "the smallest number of operations needed to get the the identity element" then the $o(3)=1$ as there is just one operation (but 2 elements) $3+3= 0 \pmod 6$

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct. You should also have mentioned that $3\not\equiv0\pmod6$.

Comment: But if $o(3)=2$ and $o(e)=1; e\in G$ for any $G$ doesn't it implies that $3\not\equiv 0\pmod6$?

Comment: @gbox Yes, of course! But strictly speaking, since $o(3)$ is the smallest natiral $n$ such that $n\times3\equiv0\pmod6$ and since all you proved was that $2\times3\equiv0\pmod6$, there was still a tiny detail missing if you wanted to prove *from the definition* that $o(3)=2$; that detail was that $1\times3\not\equiv0\pmod6$.

Comment: To me it is true.  This is representation. $3\equiv 0 (mod 6)$means $3$ and $0$ generate same subgroup. This is a contradiction of order of them.